# How do I create a list or Array in C++ and then randomly assign those objects to another variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I really am not sure which I should be using if either of those methods. But below is a script I am making about cars passing a traffic light. And once a certain amount of cars have passed, the light will change from green to yellow and yellow to red.

To add some features to the cars, I want to assign them 1 of 4 colors. I created an array, but when I run the program it looks like it assigns the array to my output but not the colors, it adds a strange code to each "car".

And if this isn't the way to go about this, what would be a better method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h> //Allow to import Sleep()
using namespace std;

void main()

{
    int cars = 0;
    string go, light;
    string testArray[4] = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "White" }; //Car colors to assign to cars passing

    cout << "The light is green \n"
        << "Type go and press enter to start cars" << endl;
    cin >> go;
    cout << "Cars that have passed the light. \n";

    do
    {
        cout << cars << " " << testArray << endl;
        cars++;
        Sleep(1000); //Delay output for 1 second
    } while (cars < 6);
    {

        cout << "Yellow light" << endl;
        cout << "There are " << cars + 10 << " cars slowing down." << endl; //cars + 10 cars slowing down on yellow light.
    }

    cout << "The light is red. There are " << cars << " cars stopped.\n";

}
```

The output is below

```
The light is green
Type go and press enter to start cars
go
Cars that have passed the light.
0 007CF72C
1 007CF72C
2 007CF72C
3 007CF72C
4 007CF72C
5 007CF72C
Yellow light
There are 16 cars slowing down.
The light is red. There are 6 cars stopped.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Since it seems you're on windows, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982398.aspx) should help. Otherwise, use [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/). Just pass the random number as an index to your array. Also, make sure it doesn't exceed the size of your array: eg. testArray[randomNumber%sizeOfArray].

Comment: I understand you are just starting. But since this is labeled C++ try to think more in objects. A light is an object. (So make it a class!) It has a property, the color; perhaps it can also keep track of the number of cars passed since turning green last. It will then change color on its own after N cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an integer that will hold the index of the colors.

```
int color_index;
do
    {
        color_index=rand()%4;
        cout << cars << " " << testArray[color_index] << endl;
        cars++;
        Sleep(1000); //Delay output for 1 second
    } while (cars < 6);
```

you can also include "srand(time(NULL));" in the main() to make sure every time u run the program will give u different random colors(not in same order).

Comment: All great answers leading to the same thing! Thank you for this bit here, worked perfect! Would not have guessed that at all to create an index for them. I can finish the script!

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array itself, not a member of it, that's why you're getting *strange numbers*, all those are memory addresses. Use `array[index]` instead, and some method like `rand() % ARRAY_SIZE` to get a random index.